# Automatically inactivate after a certain date

Tags: php, sql

I want to make an advertisment manager. When an ad reaches its expiry date it becomes non-active. But when I tried to make it and tried it, all of the ads change into non-active even though they haven't reached their expiry dates.

Here's my code:

```
$query_banner = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ad_tbl ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT $from,$max_show") or die(mysql_error());
while($show=mysql_fetch_array($query_banner))
{ 
  $no++;
  if(($no%2)==0)
    $color = '#f2f2f2'; 
  else
    $color = '#f9f9f9';

  $expired_date = $show['expiry_date'];
  $today_date = date("m/d/Y");

  $expired = strtotime($expiry_date);
  $today   = strtotime($today_date);

  if($expired > $today)
  {
    $valid = "yes";
  }
  else
  {
    $valid = "no";
    $query_expired = mysql_query("UPDATE ad_tbl SET status='Non-Active' WHERE expiry_date <= $today") or die(mysql_error());    
  }
}
```

Comment: `strtotime()` returns an integer value, whereas MySQL usually stores dates in `YYYY-mm-dd` format.

Comment: Just a tip, it would be more optimised to have status as a bit, integer or enum field (depending on the number of statuses) than a text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  $expiredDateTime = new DateTime($expiry_date);
  $expired = $expiredDateTime->format('U'); 
  $today   = date('U'); // This will default give you timestamp for "now", saving you a step
```

If that works then I fear your `m/d/y` format could be the root of the issue. To check you should echo your `strtotime` values out and stick them into a converter, see what it says.